# What gets returned by Solidity from a mapping to an array if the key doesn't exist

Tags: solidity, evm

I have a mapping between an address and an array of structs like this...

```
struct myStruct{
    string name,
    uint height
}

mapping (address=>myStruct[]) myMapping
```

if I access myMapping with an `address` key that hasn't been seen before, what gets returned?

e.g.

```
x = myMapping["unknownKey"];
```

What is in `x`? Is it `0` or `[]` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from solidity docs:

> A variable which is declared will have an initial default value whose byte-representation is all zeros. The “default values” of variables are the typical “zero-state” of whatever the type is. For example, the default value for a bool is false. The default value for the uint or int types is 0. For statically-sized arrays and bytes1 to bytes32, each individual element will be initialized to the default value corresponding to its type.

> For dynamically-sized arrays, bytes and string, the default value is
> an empty array or string. For the enum type, the default value is its
> first member.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html#default-value

So, it should be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If the value for a specific key provided to a mapping doesn't exist, then it will hold a false value, in this case an empty array.