# What gets returned by Solidity from a mapping to a struct if the key doesn't exist?

Tags: solidity, evm

This is a variation on [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124093/what-gets-returned-by-solidity-from-a-mapping-to-an-array-if-the-key-doesnt-exi/124099#124099).

I have a mapping between an address and a struct like this...

```
struct myStruct{
    string name,
    uint height
}

mapping (address=>myStruct) myMapping
```

if I access myMapping with an address key that hasn't been seen before, what gets returned?

e.g.

```
x = myMapping[unknownaddress];
```

What is in x?

I get a compile error if I compare to zero like this...

```
if (myMapping[unknownaddress] == 0){
   ...
}

Operator != not compatible with types struct MyStruct and int_const 0
```

Should I expect and "empty" or zeroed struct?

e.g.

```
x = myMapping[unknownaddress];
x.name = ""
x.height = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `x = myMapping["unknownKey"];` will return error as key for your map is address, not string.

By giving a random address:

```
myStruct public x = myMapping[0x5c6B0f7Bf3E7ce046039Bd8FABdfD3f9F5021678];
```

`x` represents an un-initialized struct. Every field of this struct will be set to the default value. In this case, your `name` field will be `empty` and `height` will be `0`. It would have been initialized to `false` if you had `bool` field. And finally, if you had `address` field, it would have been `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Here complete code:

```
struct myStruct{
    string name;
    uint height;
    bool test;
    address tryy;
}

mapping (address=>myStruct) public myMapping;

myStruct public x = myMapping[0x5c6B0f7Bf3E7ce046039Bd8FABdfD3f9F5021678];
```

By deploying on Remix, you can retrieve the value for `x` and its fields.

Comment: oops, great catch, I will adjust my question to get rid of the string key

Answer (score 0):

All unwritten storage in the EVM state is zeroed out. Thus, reading any uninitialized storage variable is zeroes, including the struct members.

[See also this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2504/620).